# Why do the Metal Ions in an Electrochemical Cell Not Pass Through a Salt Bridge?

Tags: electrochemistry

I understand that the purpose of a salt bridge is to maintain the neutrality of the solutions in an electrochemical cell, but why do the ions    being oxidized and reduced not pass through the salt bridge.

[image: Image result for copper sulfate electrochemical cell]

For example, in this electrochemical cell, why do the silver ions not pass through the salt bridge and become reduced in the copper sulfate solution. Wouldn't this cause less resistance in the circuit, or does the salt bridge prevent the metal ions from passing through?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19540/why-the-salts-in-a-salt-bridge

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19540/why-the-salts-in-a-salt-bridge

Comment: Actually the purpose is rather what you say - prevent mixing, otherwise you could just put electrodes next to each other.

Comment: They **do** pass.

Comment: The salt bridge is kind of first-in, first-out. So the ions that are already in the bridge come out first. The oxidized/reduced ions follow later.